# TextField Null em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver em JavaFX. Gostaria de poder selecionar um item em uma tableView, ao clicar em um botão, ele abrir uma janela com os detalhes do item selecionado previamente.
Porém estou enfrentando o seguinte erro: O textField está null quando tento atribuir o valor do campo do objeto ao texto do textField.

```
controller.setCliente(cliente);
if (controller.getCliente() != null)
    controller.fillForm();
```

Lá no controller:

```
txtID.setText(cliente.getId().toString());
txtNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
// São vários campos
```

Também já tentei colocar no método initialize, mas sem sucesso. Quando vou chamar o txtID, ele está null.

Agradeço a ajuda dos colegas desde já.

Comment: Não seria só atribuir uma nova instancia de TextField pra ele? `txtID = new TextField();`?

Comment: Você consegue trabalhar com a instancia do TableView?

Comment: Gustavo Cinque, então eu tenho que sempre instanciar todos os meus componentes, como no Swing? Eu pensei que no FXML isso seria automático...

Comment: Math, eu consigo trabalhar com a TableView normalmente, ela é preenchida e eu consigo capturar a linha selecionada normalmente. O erro ocorre é ao atribuir a linha selecionada (campo do objeto) ao TextField (assim como citado no código acima).

Comment: Não, você não tem que instanciar seus componentes. Você deve dar um id para ele no seu `fxml` e usar a anotação `@FXML` na sua classe para associar o id do fxml com a variável da sua classe. Pergunta: Como você fez para trabalhar com o TableView? Deve ser do mesmo jeito que deve fazer para o TextField.

Comment: Teria como você postar todo conteúdo de sua classe de controle que contem a TableView e a classe de controle da nova janela, por favor?

Comment: Se vc está tentado mostrar o item selecionado na tabela, em outra janela( ou seja, outra clase), vc teria q, adicionar no constructor da clase o Objeto selecionado. A janela, fica na mesma clase, ou em otra???